# Raw counts and percentages weighted by survey weight in R table?

Tags: r, survey, weighted, frequency-table

I'm using the R package `table1` to create a simple table of summary statistics for mostly factored variables (age categories, sex, race, etc.). The counts in the table need to be raw counts, but the percentages need to be weighted by a survey weight variable in the dataset. It seems like a simple enough task that there should be a table-making package that has a function for this, but I can't seem to find a solution in table1, flextable, gt, kableExtra, or any other package.

The example below shows roughly what I've been able to do so far, but the percentages that appear are unweighted and I can't find a way to use the `sv_weight` variable to calculate weighted percentages.

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
  year = factor(sample(c("2019", "2020"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
  sv_weight = (sample(1:150, 100, replace = TRUE)),
  sex = factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
  race =  factor(sample(c("White", "Hispanic", "Black"), 100, replace = TRUE)))

library(table1)
tab<- table1(~ sex + race | year, data = dat) 

tab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `survey` and `gtsummary` packages. There is an option in `survey::svydesign` to add weights. Then, the `survey` object is piped into `tbl_svysummary`. However, depending on your expected output, you might need to use a different statistic or adjust some of the other settings.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

results <-
  survey::svydesign(~ 1, data = dat, weights = ~ sv_weight) %>%
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = year,
    include = c(sex, race),
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n_unweighted} ({p}%)")
  )
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been so helpful. The thing I'm stuck on now is how to format missingness. I have a row within each categorical variable for the count of missing values in that variable - this appears automatically. But it looks like the count is weighted, rather than unweighted, even though the counts in other rows are unweighted. Do you know how to format the rows for missing?